# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, angular-template

I looked at similar questions, but none of them helped me.
I am going to receive an object like the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Safa",
    "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
    "purpose": "thesis",
    "programme": "Software Engineering",
    "year": 2016,
    "language": "Estonian",
    "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
    "status": "RECEIVED"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Safa",
    "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
    "purpose": "thesis",
    "programme": "Software Engineering",
    "year": 2016,
    "language": "Estonian",
    "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
    "status": "RECEIVED"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Salman",
    "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
    "purpose": "thesis",
    "programme": "Software Engineering",
    "year": 2016,
    "language": "Estonian",
    "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
    "status": "RECEIVED"
  }
]
```

and here is my http service to receive it:

```
getRequest(){
        return this._http.get("http://consultationwebserver.herokuapp.com/requests").map(res => res.json());
    }
```

and finally, in the i called the service in this way:

```
requests;
    constructor(private _http:requestService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.requests=this._http.getRequest().subscribe(res=>this.requests=res);
    }
```

Unfortunately, when the page loads it complains with:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

So, what is going wrong with this code?

Comment: Please add your template code where you are using this object.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There you don't need to use `this.requests=` when you are making `get` call(then `requests` will have observable subscription). You will get a response in observable `success` so setting  `requests` value in success make sense(which you are already doing).

```
this._http.getRequest().subscribe(res=>this.requests=res);
```

If it still shows an error related to type, add `any`/`RelevantModel` type on subscribe parameter object.

```
this._http.getRequest().subscribe(
  (res: any[]) => this.requests =res
);
```

Basically, *ngFor works for only iterable items like arrays. If you assign `this.requests` to have an object value, and you're trying to use *ngfor it will return this error.

For example, when you declare array like `this.myArray = {}` this problem will occur. It should be `this.myArray = []`.

Comment: That is not the solution for above mentioned error(Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.) 

He has to use dataType like for ex: 
`requests: any=[]`
Even i faced the same and I fixed by adding dataType

Comment: Agreed @kva the error is thrown only when it can't render the object's members

Comment: basically NgFor works for only iterable items like arrays. if you declare dictonary and trying to use *ngfor it will these type of errors. for example when you declare array like this.myArray = {}.. problem will occur.. it should be  this.myArray = []. than problem will solve.

Answer (score 19):

Remove `this.requests` from

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this.requests=this._http.getRequest().subscribe(res=>this.requests=res);
}
```

to

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this._http.getRequest().subscribe(res=>this.requests=res);
}
```

`this._http.getRequest()` returns a subscription, not the response value.
The response value is assigned by the callback passed to `subscribe(...)`

Comment: Any idea how to show the response in the console?When I do console.log(this.requests) I get a subscriber object

Comment: `this._http.getRequest().subscribe(res=>{ this.requests=res; console.log(this.requests);});`

Answer (score 12):

You can declare the books (on line 2) as an array:

```
title: any = 'List of books are represted in the bookstore';
books: any = []; 
constructor(private service:  AppService){
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getBookDetails();
}

getBookDetails() {
    this.service.getBooks().subscribe(books => {
        this.books = books.json();
        console.log(this.books);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no `books` mentioned in the question.

Comment: must say, that helped since i init'ed my array as `products = {}` and should have done `products:any = []`, since the `*ngFor` 1st ran on an empty `object` which he cant

Comment: @bresleveloper same with me.. thanks for pointing it out.. it solved my issue as well.. :)

Answer (score 9):

My solution is create a Pipe for return the values array or propierties object

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'valueArray',
})
export class ValueArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  // El parametro object representa, los valores de las propiedades o indice
  transform(objects : any = []) {
    return Object.values(objects);
  }
}
```

The template Implement

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let element of element_list | valueArray" >
    {{ element.any_property }}
</button>
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me with just one workaround...
I had to describe the return parameter of the transform function, like this
```js
transform(objects : any = []): ChildProcess[] {
...
```
Is there a more logic explanation of this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the transform syntax a bit for Angular 12 strict: https://stefvanlooveren.me/errors/corejs5980-error-error-cannot-find-differ-supporting-object-object-object-type-object-ngfor

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error because I have mapped the HTTP response like this:

```
this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json);
```

Note how I accidentally called .json like a variable and not like a method.

Changing it to:

```
this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
```

did the trick.

Comment: My problem is I did not wrap my response from the server with 'data', as recommended in the angular 2 hero tutorial

Answer (score 7):

In your JSOn file, please make below change.

```
 {
    "data":
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Safa",
        "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
        "purpose": "thesis",
        "programme": "Software Engineering",
        "year": 2016,
        "language": "Estonian",
        "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
        "status": "RECEIVED"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Safa",
        "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
        "purpose": "thesis",
        "programme": "Software Engineering",
        "year": 2016,
        "language": "Estonian",
        "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
        "status": "RECEIVED"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Salman",
        "email": "neerupeeru@mail.ee",
        "purpose": "thesis",
        "programme": "Software Engineering",
        "year": 2016,
        "language": "Estonian",
        "comments": "In need of correcting a dangling participle.",
        "status": "RECEIVED"
      }
    ]
    }
```

And after that:

```
 this.http.get(url).map(res:Response) => res.json().data);
```

The data is actually the name of tge collection of json file. Please try the code above, I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate over an object which has a json format like below

```
{
  "mango": { "color": "orange", "taste": "sweet" }
  "lemon": { "color": "yellow", "taste": "sour" }
}
```

1. Assign it to a variable

   `let rawData = { "mang":{...}, "lemon": {...} }`
2. Create a empty array(s) for holding the values(or keys)

   `let dataValues = []; //For values`

   `let dataKeys = []; //For keys`
3. Loop over the keys and add the values(and keys) to variables

   `for(let key in rawData) {   //Pay attention to the 'in'
       dataValues.push(rawData[key]);
       dataKeys.push(key);
    }`
4. Now you have an array of keys and values which you can use in *ngFor or a for loop

   `for(let d of dataValues) {
       console.log("Data Values",d);
    }`

   `<tr *ngFor='let data of dataValues'> ..... </tr>`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else with this issue that arrives here via Google, please check that the host element of the `*ngFor` directive is accurate.  By this, I mean that I encountered this error and spent a long time researching fixes before realizing that I had put the `*ngFor` on an `ng-template` element instead of on my component I wanted to repeat.

**Incorrect**

```
<ng-template *ngFor=let group of groups$ | async" ...>
  <my-component [prop1]="group.key" ... </my-component>
<\ng-template>
```

**Correct**

```
<my-component *ngFor=let group of groups$ | async" [prop1]="group.key" ... </my-component>
```

I know this is an obvious mistake in hindsight, but I hope an answer here will save someone the headache I now have.

Answer (score 3):

i have the same problem. this is how i fixed the problem.
first when the error is occurred, my array data is coming form DB like this --,

```
{brands: Array(5), _id: "5ae9455f7f7af749cb2d3740"}
```

make sure that your data is an ARRAY, not an OBJECT that carries an array. only array look like this --,

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use async pipe. Doc: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

For example:

```
<li *ngFor="let a of authorizationTypes | async"[value]="a.id">
     {{ a.name }}
</li>
```

Comment: This approach solved my problem. It was before I read this answer, but It worth to let others know that your approach works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i have faced same problem

my initial json

```
{"items":

         [
           {"id":1,
            "Name":"test4"
           },
           {"id":2,
            "Name":"test1"
           }
         ]
}
```

i have changed my json inside []

```
[{"items":

         [
           {"id":1,
            "Name":"test4"
           },
           {"id":2,
            "Name":"test1"
           }
         ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.requests=res` here you are trying to assign following response to object,

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK",
"url":"xyz","ok":true,"type":4,"body":[{}]}
```

Since, object format is different then response format you have to assign `res.body` part from your response to get required contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor = "let Data of allDataFromAws  | async">
  <pre> {{ Data | json}}</pre>
</li>
</ul>
```

use async to convert allDataFromAws into Array Object....

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the **var** as an **array** in which you holding the data , it worked for me.

```
listingdata:Array<any> = [];
this.listingdata = data.results.rows;
```

and loop the listingdata on html page

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

When you are receiving array from your database. and you are storing array data inside a variable but the variable defined as object. This time you will get the error.

I am receiving array from database and I'm stroing that array inside a variable 'bannersliders'. 'bannersliders' type is now 'any' but if you write 'bannersliders' is an object. Like bannersliders:any={}. So this time you are storing array data inside object type variable. So you find that error.

So you have to write variable like 'bannersliders:any;' or 'bannersliders:any=[]'.

Here I am giving an example.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
bannersliders:any;
  getallbanner(){
    this.bannerService.getallbanner().subscribe(data=>{
      this.bannersliders =data;
   })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In you use spring boot with  Angular ; make sure that whether you create default

Comment: make sure that you should use default constructor

Answer (score 0):

*********** PARSE THE RESULT TO JSON OBJECT: JSON.prase(result.arrayOfObjects) ***********

I came to this page after I faced this issue. So, my issue was that the server is sending array of objects in the form of string. It is something like this:

when I printed result on console after getting from server it is string:

```
'arrayOfObject': '[
                  {'id': '123', 'designation': 'developer'},
                  {'id': '422', 'designation': 'lead'}
               ]'
```

So, I have to convert this string to JSON after getting it from server. Use method for parsing the result string that you receive from server:

```
JSON.parse(result.arrayOfObjects)
```

Comment: The above one is a scenario where the result you are getting is in the string data type. So, check the data type and if it is string parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Store that objects into Array  and then iterate the Array
export class AppComponent {

 public obj: object =null;
 public myArr=[];

  constructor(){

    this.obj = {
      jon : {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
      lucy : {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
      mike : {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
      luke : {username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'},
      james : {username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'},
      dave : {username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'},
      sarah : {username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'},
      natalie : {username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'}
  }
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.populateCode();
  }

  populateCode(){
    for( let i in this.obj) {   //Pay attention to the 'in'
    console.log(this.obj[i]);
    this.myArr.push(this.obj[i]);
  }
  }
 }



<div *ngFor="let item of myArr ">
    {{item.username}}
    {{item.genrePref}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if someone would get the same thing as me, and I have no idee why this happens (maybe is a bug?), but I actually had this error because only because we were trying to create a ComponentPortal for an angular overlay like this:

```
const smartfillPortal = new ComponentPortal(
  SmartFillModalComponent,
  this.viewContainerRef,
  {
    get: () => this.smartfillOverlayRef,
  }
);
```

changing it to

```
const smartfillPortal = new ComponentPortal(SmartFillModalComponent);
```

fixed it for some reason (I am guessing I am also missing some info about overlays?).

The weird thing is that even something like this in the overlay code:

```
<div class="flex" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]; let i = index">
  <span>hi there</span>
</div>
```

would result in

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '1,2,3' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also change how you access the property. I faced this issue and
instead of accessing :

this.someService.details

I've used :

this.someService['details'];

This fixed this error for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me the error was resolved when I added the index to *ngFor.

```html
<tr *ngFor = "let element of element_list; let i=index">
             <td>{{element.id}}</td>
             <td>{{element.status}}</td>
             <td>{{element.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```