# How to loop through multiple Arrays inside Json Object

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I am trying to loop through multiple arrays inside a json object.
Here is a picture of the structure of json object.

[image]

I have been trying loop through it using ngFor, but I am getting an error. Here is the code of how I am trying to loop through:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
{{conversation}}
 </ion-item>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I need to be able to loop through all the arrays and but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an array of arrays but an Object with numeric keys with arrays as properties. How is the original object generated?

Comment: Original object is generated via a API call, data from that API call is being returned in this format

Comment: I am pretty sure ng-repeat got replaced with ngfor in angular 2 ?

Comment: post your JSON here. the way you are accessing the JSON seems wrong.

Comment: Will you please post the output of objects of json array?

Comment: The question doesnt contains full information and even `Duplicate for` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819392/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - \*ngFor / loop through json object with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215049/angular2-ngfor-loop-through-json-object-with-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// in component.ts
data = [];
constructor() {
  for (let item of Object.keys(your_object)) {
    this.data.push(your_object[item]);
  }
}

// in component's template
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">
    <span *ngFor="let i of d">{{i}}</data>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried it out, I get this error `caused by: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined`

Comment: Validate your json seems something issue with Json

Comment: I did Json seems to be fine

Comment: Is your json only contaning JSON of arrays or it contains array as well as objects together

Comment: It is containing JSON of arrays

Comment: @DN0300 I've updated my current code that worked to me, you can try.