# Angular2 - *ngFor / loop through json object with array

Tags: angular

Want to loop through json object

```
//Defined on component side :
jsonObj = {
    '1' : [ {"title" : "title1" , "desc" : "desc1" }],
    '2' : [ {"title" : "title2" , "desc" : "desc2" }],
    '3' : [ {"title" : "title3" , "desc" : "desc3" }],
    '4' : [ {"title" : "title4" , "desc" : "desc4" }],
    '5' : [ {"title" : "title5" , "desc" : "desc5" }]
}
```

With `*ngFor` **only on template side** , 
And **without any coding (function) on component side**.

Want to print just each `title` and `desc`

**Is this possible ? If Yes ? How ?**

Comment: I dont think its possible without pipe or formating inside component.ts

Comment: without any "coding on component side" I don't think. But if you're ok to add a pipe then yes : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35261193/2398593

Comment: I know all the other way , just trying to do it on template side @Maxime , Sajeetharan , thanks for your time , let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: Any Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So great to find the best solution from Angular itself provides pipe to loop through JSON , and its `keyvalue`**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of jsonObj | keyvalue'>
   Key: {{item.key}}

    <div *ngFor='let obj of item.value'>
        {{ obj.title }}
        {{ obj.desc }}
    </div>

</div>
```

**[WORKIGN DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-loop-pipe)**

---

**Previously :**

> Component side :

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

> Template side :

```
<div *ngFor='let key of objectKeys(jsonObj)'>
   Key: {{key}}

    <div *ngFor='let obj of jsonObj[key]'>
        {{ obj.title }}
        {{ obj.desc }}
    </div>

</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-key-loop)**