# How do I loop through json with arrays and get all the value?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"success": false,
"error": {
    "username": [
        "The username has already been taken."
    ],
    "email_address": [
        "The email address has already been taken."
    ]
}
}
```

I want to store all the messages in an array. Right now, I'm doing it manually by checking one by one. Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - \*ngFor / loop through json object with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215049/angular2-ngfor-loop-through-json-object-with-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Object.keys` method that will return an array with the `error` keys.
Then you can iterate it with any `Array` method such as `map`, `forEach`, `reduce` to collect the messages them-self.

```js
const response = {
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "username": [
      "The username has already been taken.",
      "Another message"
    ],
    "email_address": [
      "The email address has already been taken."
    ]
  }
};

const result = Object.keys(response.error)
  .reduce((acc, key) => acc.concat(response.error[key]), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Undefined values are stored in array, although the number is right.

Comment: So, I would use `reduce` in order to collect all the messages. will update my answer

Comment: Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get all the messages in a array

```
var a = {
"success": false,
"error": {
    "username": [
        "The username has already been taken."
    ],
    "email_address": [
        "The email address has already been taken."
    ]
}
}
var keys = Object.keys(a['error'])
var errors = a['error']

var c = [];
for(var i=0; i< keys.length; i++){
    c.push(a['error'][keys[i]][0])
}
console.log(c)
```