# Angular 2 Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-observables

I have created a simple C# Web API service which basically returns Countries like below;

```
[
    {
        "WeatherHistory": [],
        "CountryID": 4,
        "Country": "Malaysia"
    },
    {
        "WeatherHistory": [],
        "CountryID": 5,
        "Country": "Maldives"
    },
    {
        "WeatherHistory": [],
        "CountryID": 6,
        "Country": "Mali"
    },
    {
        "WeatherHistory": [],
        "CountryID": 7,
        "Country": "Malta"
    }
]
```

And I am trying to create a simple Angular 2 application with Observables to list countries into Angular Material AutoComplete component.

Service.ts:

```
 getCountries(searchTerm: string): Observable<Countries[]> {

    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}${searchTerm}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
      .map(res => 
      {
        console.log(res.text());
        return res.json().map
        (response => <Countries[]>response.json())
        .data as Countries[];
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // debugger;
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
  private loading: boolean = false;
  WeatherSearchForm: FormGroup;
  filteredCountries: any;
  countries: Observable<Countries[]>;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService, private fb: FormBuilder) 
  {
    this.filteredCountries = this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .map(name => this.filterCountries(name));
  }

  filterCountries(val: string) {
    // return val ? this.countries.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
    //            : this.countries;
    return this.countries;
  }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do(_ => this.loading = true)
      .switchMap(country => this.weatherService.getCountries(country))
      .do(_ => 
        {
          this.loading = false; 
          console.log(this.countries); 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.countries));
        });
      // .subscribe(c => console.log(JSON.stringify(c)));

  }
```

Html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Select Country" [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
  formControlName="country">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete"
md-min-length="1" md-select-on-match>
  <md-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async" [value]="country">
    {{ country }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

And I'm getting this error as soon as when I type into Autocomplete control.

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.es5.js:1659)

I believe I need to make a change on web Api side.
Because I have succesfully tested(everything same in the code) with Itunes Search API and it works. But the only difference is ITunes search api returns following JSON response.

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=test&media=music&limit=1

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":258535972, "collectionId":258615649, "trackId":258618600, "artistName":"Little Dragon", "collectionName":"Little Dragon", "trackName":"Test", "collectionCensoredName":"Little Dragon", "trackCensoredName":"Test", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/little-dragon/id258535972?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/test/id258615649?i=258618600&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/test/id258615649?i=258618600&uo=4", 
"previewUrl":"http://audio.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview62/v4/e6/77/4e/e6774eeb-b2d3-f214-84db-38d06b53563f/mzaf_7017187472362467720.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/73/aa/cd/73aacdee-0259-fda7-3e6f-28433c098b38/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/73/aa/cd/73aacdee-0259-fda7-3e6f-28433c098b38/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/73/aa/cd/73aacdee-0259-fda7-3e6f-28433c098b38/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"2007-08-28T07:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":10, "trackTimeMillis":268040, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Electronic", "isStreamable":true}]
}
```

And when I call Itunes search api, I'm only adding "results" tag like below;

```
return res.json().results.map(item => {
```

Any help would be appreciated much.

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39819416)