# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. uncatachable

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am unable to figure out this issue. My data which is array of object passing to html and I am getting following error.

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Html file

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *ngIf="userRes" >
  <div *ngFor="let link of userRes">
  <h6 [ngClass]="{'dropdown-header': link.type === 'header', 'dropdown-item': link.type === ''}" i18n *ngIf="link.type != 'separtor'">{{link.title}} </h6>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"  *ngIf="link.type == 'separator'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Data
(5) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

```
 links=
  [
  {
     type:'header',
     title:'Account'
  },

  {
     title:'Profile',
     description:'View your profile',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/profile/url/here',
  },
  {
     title:'Board',
     description:'View your board',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/board/url/here',
  },
  {
     type:'separator'
  },
  {
     title:'Settings',
     description:'Manage your settings',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/settings/url/here',
  }

]
```

component.ts

```
      this.userRes = this.userIntermediateService.userDetail(1)
  .subscribe(value => {

    console.log(value);
   let userRes= Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key])
    console.log(this.userRes);
  })
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `links` or `userRes`?

Comment: link is array of object. userRes is a variable

Comment: so try it with `links`. `*ngFor="let link of links"`

Comment: @Hadi I have edited the code please check.

Comment: And you're still trying to iterate through userRes, which is not an array. It's a Subscription. You can't iterate through a Subscription. Your links array is irrelevant, since you're iterating through userRes: `*ngFor="let link of userRes"`

Comment: what is your array of objects and how is the data can you list @NituDhaka

Comment: @RahulSingh Please check question now. I have edited.

Comment: @NituDhaka it's now time for you to read the comments you got. And re-read them until you make sense of them. You're iterating over userRes. userRes is a Subscription, not an array. You keep posting the array named links, but you're not iterating over that array. You're iterating over userRes. Have you read this comment? If there is something you don't understand in this comment, what is it?

Comment: @NituDhaka aravind and jb have already answered that ? i guess. hope its working now .

Answer (score 0):

You are having the variable as `links` but your ngFor takes `userRes`

```
userRes= [
  {
     type:'header',
     title:'Account'
  },

  {
     title:'Profile',
     description:'View your profile',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/profile/url/here',
  },
  {
     title:'Board',
     description:'View your board',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/board/url/here',
  },
  {
     type:'separator'
  },
  {
     title:'Settings',
     description:'Manage your settings',
     url:'http://www.test.com/user/settings/url/here',
  }

]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/lQaq6mTI5p6qfWwLGLCB?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this.userRes =` use only below code

```
this.userIntermediateService.userDetail(1)
  .subscribe((value) => {

    console.log(value);
   this.userRes= Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key])
    console.log(this.userRes);
  });
```

you can refer this answer [Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819392/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor)