# Complex object binding in Angular 5 - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, object, binding

I need to binding a complex object from webapi to the Angular5 view with ngFor, but I have not been able to solve the following error:

> "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
> 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

I expose my code:

**Model.ts**

```
export interface Products {
  products: Product[];
}

export interface Product{
  id: string;
  productStats: ProductStat[];
  number: string;
}

export interface ProductStat {
  description: string;
  relevantProducts: string[];
  weight: number;
}
```

**Services.ts**

```
getProducts(productList: string[]): Observable<Products> {
    var body = JSON.stringify(productList);
    var postHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    postHeaders = postHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.httpClient.post<Products>(
           this.clientAppService.getProducts, body, { headers: postHeaders})
               .map(response => { return response; });
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
productResponse: Products;

getProducts() {
    this.productsInputFormatted = this.getProductsInputFormat(this.productsInput);     
    this.productService.getProducts(this.productsInputFormatted).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.products = data;
        //I tried to convert the following line into array, 
        //but I get the same error(this.result is 
        //declared --> result: any[]; 
        //and I changed the value of NgFor in the view) 
        this.result = Array.of(this.productsResponse); 
        alert(this.result[0].products[0].id) //I can see the value
      });
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let response of products">
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ response.products.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ response.products.number}}</td>
                        ...
```

Any idea will be of great help.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

There are other doubts with the same error, but in this case, I'm using the Observable function correctly.

I also edit to add the solution to the first answer and ask a second question:

**Error:**

Component.ts: `this.products = data;`

Component.html: `<tbody *ngFor="let response of products">>`

**Solution:**
In the first answer:

Component.ts: `this.result = Array.of(this.productsResponse);`

Component.html: `<tbody *ngFor="let response of results[0].products">`

**Second Question**

How I access to second level of my object ( productStats.description and productStat.relevantProducts[])?

Can I used nested ngFors with ng-template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find a differ supporting object '\[object Object\]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819392/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor)

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` and add the JSON to your question please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over,

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let response of results[0].products">
 <tr>
    <td>{{ response.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ response.number}}</td>
```

Comment: no on the second line OP has used   alert(this.result[0].products[0].id) . so it should be as above

Comment: It's the solution!

I had a Typo with the different tests I did. I am noob with Angular and Typescript and I have another questions: 

How I access to second level of my object ( productStats.description and productStat.relevantProducts[])? Can I used nested ngFors? 

Thank you very much!!