# "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. ..."

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to show `name`, but save as it's value of `_id` for `mat-select`.
And save it's value in `selectedIngridient`, for selecting an option.

I get:

> "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

But I was looking at different post(e.g.: [Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819392/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor)), couldn't figure out the error.

What did I do wrong ?

Stacklitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l6yvgd?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Init:

```
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
  allIngridients: Observable<Ingridient[]>;
  selectedIngridient: Ingridient;
```

DataLayer:

```
    export class Ingridient {
    _id: string;

    name: string;// todo: Übersetzungen
    barCode?: Barcode;

    constructor() {
        this._id = UUID.UUID();
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
      <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Select an ingridient" [(value)]="selectedIngridient">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let ingridient of allIngridients" [value]="ingridient._id">
                {{ingridient.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Fill `allIngridients`(calling in `constructor`):

```
  inlineFunction_IngridientsNumberAndUnits_Ingridient(recipeId: string, anzahl: number): Ingridient[] {
    let result: Ingridient[] = [];

    for (let i_result = 0; i_result < anzahl; i_result++) {

      // todo: später mit recipe
      const tag: Ingridient = new Ingridient(recipeId);

      // Code
      tag.name = "Unit_" + (i_result + 1);
      tag.name = "BarCodes_" + (i_result + 1);

      // todo: changed
      this.allIngridients.subscribe(current => {
        current.push(tag);
      })

      result.push(tag);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I was composing an answer for you but Jota marked it as dup.

Answer (score 0):

The below line is not array that's why you cannot iterate over it. It's observable to hold array. You need to subscribe and assign result to an array and then iterate over it.

`allIngridients: Observable<Ingridient[]>;`

Or use `| async` pipe:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let ingridient of allIngridients | async" [value]="ingridient._id">
```

Comment: but I got a subscribe: ` this.allIngridients.subscribe(current => {
        current.push(tag);
      })`, its different ? When I use `| async` i get no error, but nothing to display ...

Comment: @StartingAgain Did you try using async pipe?

Comment: @StartingAgain You did subscribe but instead of pulling you are pushing. You need to use async pipe or assign your subscription result to `array` and iterate over that array.

Comment: I was trying https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l6yvgd?file=src/app/app.module.ts , may be this helps ?

Comment: "ou did subscribe but instead of pulling you are pushing.", yes , because I want to fill it with some data ...